# Sk Physics Joint not working properly

Tags: physics, game-physics, skphysicsbody, skphysicsjoint

I am creating a game and for my character his legs and torso have separate animations so they are separate nodes with separate physics bodies. I am having a lot of trouble linking the torso and the legs together however, linking them is not the problem, keeping them linked is. While moving around sometimes the hero's torso slides off of the legs. Kind of funny but not practical lol. Here is my physics coding

```
enum BodyType:UInt32 {

case bullet1 = 2

case enemy1 =  4
case enemy2 =  16
case enemy3 =  32

case desertForegroundCase = 64

case tank11 =  128
case tank12 =  256
case tank13 =  512

case tank21 =  1024
case tank22 =  2048
case tank23 =  4056

case tank31 =  8112
case tank32 =  16224
case tank33 =  32448

case cliff1 =  64856
case cliff2 =  129212

case soldierT = 258424
case soldierL = 516848

}

 func CreateScene (){

desertBackground.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: 
frame.size.height / 2)
desertBackground.size = CGSize (width: 1136, height: 640)
desertBackground.zPosition = -5
desertForegroundImage.position = CGPointMake(568, 100)
desertForegroundImage.zPosition = -1
let desertForeground = SKSpriteNode(texture: 
desertForegroundTexture, size:CGSize(width: 1136, height: 200))
    desertForeground.position = CGPointMake(568, 100)
let desertForegroundBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: 
desertForegroundTexture, size: CGSize(width: 1136, height: 200))
desertForegroundBody.dynamic = false
desertForegroundBody.affectedByGravity = false
desertForegroundBody.allowsRotation = false
desertForegroundBody.categoryBitMask = 
BodyType.deserForegroundcase.rawValue
desertForegroundBody.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.enemy1.rawValue 
| BodyType.enemy2.rawValue | BodyType.enemy3.rawValue  | 
BodyType.soldierL.rawValue | BodyType.soldierT.rawValue
desertForeground.physicsBody = desertForegroundBody
desertForeground.zPosition = -1

self.addChild(desertForegroundImage)
self.addChild(desertForeground)
self.addChild(desert gully)

}
func CreateHero (){

soldierLegs.position = CGPoint(x: 405 , y: 139)
soldierLegs.zPosition = 1
soldierLegs.anchorPoint.x = 0.6
soldierLegs.anchorPoint.y = 0.7

let soldierLegsBody:SKPhysicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: 
soldierLegs.size)
soldierLegsBody.dynamic = true
soldierLegsBody.affectedByGravity = true
soldierLegsBody.allowsRotation = false
//body.restitution = 0.4
soldierLegsBody.categoryBitMask = BodyType.soldierL.rawValue
soldierLegsBody.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.enemy1.rawValue | 
BodyType.enemy2.rawValue | BodyType.enemy3.rawValue  | 
BodyType.desertForegroundCase.rawValue
soldierLegs.physicsBody = soldierLegsBody

soldierTorso.position = soldierLegs.position
soldierTorso.zPosition = 2
soldierTorso.anchorPoint.x = 0.25
soldierTorso.anchorPoint.y = 0.1

let soldierTorsoBody:SKPhysicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: 
soldierTorso.size)
soldierTorsoBody.dynamic = true
soldierTorsoBody.affectedByGravity = true
soldierTorsoBody.allowsRotation = false
soldierTorsoBody.categoryBitMask = BodyType.soldierT.rawValue
soldierTorsoBody.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.enemy1.rawValue | 
BodyType.enemy2.rawValue | BodyType.enemy3.rawValue  | 
BodyType.desertForegroundCase.rawValue
soldierTorso.physicsBody = soldierTorsoBody
let joint  = 
SKPhysicsJointFixed.jointWithBodyA(soldierLegs.physicsBody!, bodyB: 
soldierTorso.physicsBody!, anchor: soldierLegs.position)

self.addChild(soldierTorso)
self.addChild(soldierLegs)
self.physicsWorld.addJoint(joint)
}
```

[image]

That's about how far he will slide off. Is there a way to just code one physics body with 2 separate nodes? or am i just missing a little code? Any help is help, thank you.

Comment: @appzyourlife can you help?